# Jquery roundabout carousel does not round about

Tags: jquery

I want to create a carousel using the roundabout jquery plugin. I am trying to enhance it with showing a title for each slide and a button, with which each slide is selectable on its own.  I do not know why it is not working, any help would be highly appreciated!

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kampfkuchen/t5DQr/

Here is the javascript, where most likely the mistake was made:

```
(function($) {

var $descriptions = $('#carousel-descriptions').children('li'),
$controls = $('#carousel-controls').find('span'),
$carousel = $('#carousel')
    .roundabout({childSelector:"img", minOpacity:1, autoplay:true, autoplayDuration:5000, autoplayPauseOnHover:true })
    .on('focus', 'img', function() {
        var slideNum = $carousel.roundabout("getChildInFocus");

        $descriptions.add($controls).removeClass('current');
        $($descriptions.get(slideNum)).addClass('current');
        $($controls.get(slideNum)).addClass('current');
    });

$controls.on('click dblclick', function() {
var slideNum = -1,
    i = 0, len = $controls.length;

for (; i<len; i++) {
    if (this === $controls.get(i)) {
        slideNum = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (slideNum >= 0) {
    $controls.removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $carousel.roundabout('animateToChild', slideNum);
}
});

}(jQuery));
```

Thank you very much already! :)

Comment: Is this problem resolved? Just in case its not, please update your fiddle to include a real link to roundabout.js. The current link `<script src="jquery.roundabout.js"></script>` isn't helping.

Comment: Thank you! But it is not relevant anymore!